# Using LazySizes to Lazy Load Images but Want to Maintain the Space Around the Image when Loading In

Tags: css, lazy-loading

I am using LazySizes to lazy load images. I am using Bootstrap as a framework for the HTML & CSS but am having trouble trying to allow the space around the image be maintained while the image loads in, so the image doesn't appear to fill in the space between the text it surrounds. Almost like how an image would appear to regularly load on the page, with the space maintained around it, while it loads in, when you're not lazyloading.

I have already tried specifying the width and height as well as added the width specification to the data-srcset, the HTML of the image, and used data-sizes="auto", but this isn't helping. My thought is adding a CSS customization so the space of the image is maintained before it loads but I am wondering if there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add an src= attribute of a lower quality image to allow something to maintain the space until the image lazyloaded in. This way it appears to maintain the same behavior as an image that is loaded in without lazyloading.